# The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to run a local project,there is no remote debugger or online sharing.It used to work fine early, now Visual Studio Shows this message.
Why does it show this message?  I dont even need remote debugging.

[image]

Comment: MSVSMON.exe is also used when you try to debug a 64-bit app.  Required because VS is a 32-bit app.  Why it won't start is hard to guess, try a reboot first, try tinkering with anti-malware, try setting the Platform target of the EXE project to x86.

Comment: @HansPassant The platform Target is X86.I have also noticed that when i load the old version of the project and try to debug it,there are no issues.It runs smoothly.But when i load the new version,things go like this.And there is also a Remote Operation is taking too long .. window when i load the new project

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't help, you need to tell us what is different between the "old" and "new" project.  Compare the .csproj files.  And do keep in mind that the Solution Platform name doesn't have anything to do with the EXE project's Platform target setting, the one you set with Project + Properties, Build tab.  And keep in mind that your machine is pretty messed up when it can't start msvsmon.exe or you get "taking too long" window.  And try starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe yourself with Explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant I will clean up the system using ccleaner,antimalware and install VS2013 ,now im using VS2012 and get back

Comment: @HansPassant Its Visual Studio 11.0.I tried opening it manually a window came up saying MSVSMON has been started with server and stuff.Along with it came a windows firewall message http://i.imgur.com/y4Nohnv.png